# Linked list Recursion ...

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'd like to make a recursive function using C++

I make this class

```
class linklist
{
private:
  struct node
  {
    int data;
    node *link;
  }*p;
};

void linklist::print_num(node* p)
{
  if (p != NULL) 
  {
    cout << p->data << " ";
    print_num (p->link);
  }
}
```

in the main program what should I write ...

Comment: You did not specify what the function should do.

Comment: Um, recursion doesn't make sense for traversing a linked list...

Comment: Your `print_num` method already *is* recursive...

Comment: @egrunin Why not? Compilers will do appropriate transformation for tail-recursion.

Comment: Whatever you need to do to fill the linked list with data and call `print_num` on it.

Comment: @ony It does depend on what he means to do, I guess we have to wait and see...

Comment: you need to at least add a pointer to the first node in your class, then use that to print and add nodes.

Comment: Are you trying to win some kind of award for "most random code formatting"? Just tried to fix it up a bit

Comment: @jalf to be fair, the code formatter in SO is absolutely awful

Comment: @NomeN: I don't have any problem with it. Paste code, select code, click 'code' button. Anyway, look at the original version of the question and tell me it's the code formatter's fault. ;)

Comment: @jalf I think I have 2 problems with the code formatter. 1, I use tabs. 2, I push the code button and then paste my code in that space.
The second issue, is stupid but I'm willing to relearn. The first is just bloody annoying.

Comment: @NomeN: Agreed on the first count. But I think it's pretty clear by looking at the OP's original question that tabs vs spaces wasn't the cause of his weird formatting. :)

Comment: @chris: please don't tag questions as homework unless the OP states that it is indeed homework, or unless you have a crystal ball.

Answer (score 2):

1: Build the list
2: Retain the first node
3: `print_num` on the first node

I had to change a lot in your code to make it work. I'm guessing you used to write Java...

But in my main I get:

```
node *first = NULL;
for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    node *temp =  new node;
    temp->data = i;
    temp->link = first; 
    first = temp;
}

linklist::print_num(first);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok, apparently you didn't get what you should do with this piece of code, so I am now posting the whole thing for you. Consider yourself very lucky, and try to learn from it.
If you still have issues please make your question/requirements clearer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {  
    int data;
    node *link;
};

class linklist {
public:

    static void print_num(node* p) {
    if (p != NULL)    {   
           cout << p->data << " ";
        print_num (p->link);    
       }
    }
};

int main() {
    node *first = NULL;
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        node *temp =  new node;
        temp->data = i;
        temp->link = first; 
        first = temp;
    }

    linklist::print_num(first);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After your code was reformatted, I noticed that you wanted to keep the node struct hidden.
To be able to do that, you do need an add method in your class which can add the nodes and a print method which you can call without a node.

So with that in mind I came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class linklist {
public:
    linklist();

    void print();
    void add(int number);

private:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node *link;
    };
    void print_num(node *p);
    node* start;
};

linklist::linklist() {
    start = NULL;
}

void linklist::print() {
    print_num(start);
}

void linklist::add(int number) {
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = number;
    temp->link = start;
    start = temp;
}

void linklist::print_num(node *p) {
    if (p != NULL)    {   
        cout << p->data << " ";
        print_num (p->link);    
    }
}

int main() {
    linklist list;
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    list.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no at all 'cause I should use the recursion in my algorithme ... yes,the both algorithmes are true ..what I need is what should I write in the main function to apply my class ...

Comment: @epsilon_G it is what should go in your main.